# How can i customize login api from djoser package?

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, djoser

I just want to give a user details in a login response,

currently, I'm getting `'token'` and `'refresh'` in 
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/jwt/create/` JWT login API response.

I want to return with login user details

here is the response snapshot of `jwt/create/`,

[JWT Response Image](https://prnt.sc/py4n4a)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As djoser uses [django-rest-framework-simplejwt](https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt) inside, you have to call your custom view instead of the TokenObtainPairView to add user's details in api response.
You can achieve this through following steps:

**your_app/urls.py**

You have to create your own custom url in order to customize JWT Create API's response.Add the below url path above the **"djoser.urls"** path so that this url gets called instead of djoser's package jwt/create url.

```
from your_app.views import CustomTokenObtainPairView   

urlpatterns = [
...
path('auth/jwt/token/', CustomTokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='custom_token_obtain_pair'),
]
```

**your_app/views.py**

Now add your custom view class and its corresponding serializer class where you can add user attributes for your api response.

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView

class CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):

    def validate(self, attrs):
        ## This data variable will contain refresh and access tokens
        data = super().validate(attrs)
        ## You can add more User model's attributes like username,email etc. in the data dictionary like this.
        data['user_name'] = self.user.username
        return data


class CustomTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer
```

Comment: Hey Vikas, were you able to customize the response?